# Can't put limits to randint in python

Tags: python, random

Also the program doesn't show any error. And I can't find my error. When I run this code it says that my random number is either infinitely higher or lower

```py
import random

def game1():
    print("Hello I guessed a number, try to find it")
    my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
    a = random.randint(1,5)
    number_of_tries = 1
    while a !=  my_number:
        if a > my_number:
            print("Your number must be higher")
            number_of_tries = number_of_tries+1
            player_guess = int(input("Guess the number:"))
        if a < my_number:
            print("Your number must be lower")
            number_of_tries = number_of_tries + 1
            player_guess = int(input("Guess the number:"))
        if a == my_number:
            print("Congrats, you guessed the number")
            print("Number of guesses is:", number_of_tries)
            break

game1()
```

Comment: In the middle of the program, you change the name of the user's guess from `my_number` to `player_guess`.  Meanwhile, the number they're supposed to guess is `a`??  Give your variables meaningful and consistent names: `number_to_guess` and `player_guess`.  Using `my_number` to mean their number confused both of us.

Comment: omg, I'm so stupid. I was searching for errors for an hour, thank you guys))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you assign the subsequent guesses to `player_guess` rather than `my_number`...

I'd tidy the code up to something like:

```
a = random.randint(1, 5)
number_of_tries = 0

print("Hello I guessed a number, try to find it")

while True:
    my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
    number_of_tries += 1

    if a == my_number:
        break

    if a > my_number:
        print("Your number must be higher")
    if a < my_number:
        print("Your number must be lower")

print("Congrats, you guessed the number")
print("Number of guesses is:", number_of_tries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Required very little correction. just replace `player_guess` with `my_number`.

Basically, you are comparing `a` with `my_number`, and at first you store user input to `my_number`, if it is matched there is no problem. but when it don't match and the user requested to give another guess, the input stored in `player_guess`, but still compare `a` with `player_guess` (rather then with `my_number`). this should be corrected.